# Scenic train journey in Montenegro?

Tags: montenegro

Can anyone recommend a scenic train journey purely within ME (so not onwards to Belgrade or other border destinations)? Is the Bar - Podgorica line nice, or better to change at Podgorica and get another train further north? Ideally doable within a day - we have to get back to Budva from Bar by bus.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you haven't seen it yet, check out Seat61.com: http://www.seat61.com/belgrade-to-bar-railway.htm

Comment: This question will be more answerable if you phrase it more like "I am considering X or Y. Which has better Z?" - or is cheaper, or quicker, or whatever. "Nice" is not something you can ask other people to evaluate. Choosing from the entire set of possible trips isn't something you can ask other people to do. Be clear and crisp, not about what you want to decide, but about what **information** you need in order to make the decision yourself.

Comment: Shitting hell - I feel like I've been admonished by a school head. Whilst, yes, "nice" is decidedly unspecific, subjective term, I did mention scenery. To be fair, I didn't specify what colour hills I'd like, which is my bad. I am not choosing between X and Y, nor trying to find which of two options is cheaper. I was just after simple, all-suggestions-welcome, friendly suggestions.

Comment: And thank you, @John Zwink, I'll read the link you provided.